# Question about Lebesgue point in Fourier Transform (Big Rudin chapter 9)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

To prove the Inversion Theorem of Fourier Transforms,he used the kernel:

$$h_{\lambda}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^{2}+x^{2}},
      \qquad \lambda>0$$

In his book page 194 Exer 10 and page 250 Exer 10,I have to prove:

> If $f$ $\in L^{1}$, prove that $(f \ast h_{\lambda})(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e. as $\lambda\to 0$

I tried:

\begin{align}
   |(f \ast h_{\lambda})(x)-f(x)|
   &\leq \int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} \frac{|f(x-t)-f(x)|}{\lambda}\cdot h_1(t/λ)\, dm(t)\\
    &\qquad+ \left|\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda}(f(x-t)+f(x+t)-2f(x))\cdot h_{\lambda}(t)\, dm(t)\right|
   \end{align}

First integral converges to $0$, if $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$. But I don't know how to deal with the second integral.

I will appreciate your help

Some details and results in his book :

1. $m$ for Lebesgue measure on $R^1$ divided by $\sqrt{2\pi}$
2. $(f\ast g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-y)\,g(y)\,dm(y)$
3. If $1\leq p<\infty$ and $f\in L^{p} $, then :
   $$
       \lim_{λ\to 0}\|f\ast h_{\lambda} - f\|_{p}=0
       $$

Comment: Please edit so that the long formula contains the correct identity $h_λ(t)=h_1(t/λ)/λ$ and apply the substitution $t=λs$ consistently.

Comment: Triangle inequality and norm properties on the last bit breaks into $\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda} |f(x-t)-f(x)|h_\lambda(t)dm(t)+\int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda} 
|f(x+t)-f(x)|h_\lambda(t)dm(t)$

Comment: I tried,but I don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in Big Rudin chapter 11  page 242-244.Actually,$h_{\lambda}$ is the
Poisson kernel for the half plane(page 252  Exer 24  and Exer 25).

Here's some terminologies:

Denote the open ball with center $x\in R^{1}$ and radius $r> 0$ by

$$B(x,r)= {y\in R^1:|y-x|<r}$$

,associate to any complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $R^1$ the quotients

$$(Q_{r}\mu)(x)=\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))}$$

whrer  $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $R^1$ divided by $\sqrt{2\pi}$,and define the symmetric  derivative 
      $$
        (D\mu)(x)= 
    \lim_{r\to 0}(Q_{r}\mu)(x)
    $$
   at those points $x\in R^1$ at which this limit exists.

Define maximal function $M\mu$

$$
        (M\mu)(x)= 
    \sup_{0<r<\infty}(Q_{r}|\mu|)(x)
    $$
  If $\mu$  is a complex Borel measure on $R^1$,we will write $u=P[d\mu]$ whose domain is the upper half plane :

$$u(x,\lambda)=\int_{R^1}h_{\lambda}(x-t)d\mu(t)$$  $$(0<\lambda,x\in R^1)$$

$$ (M_{rad}u)(x)=sup(|u(x,r)|:0<\lambda<\infty)$$

Here's the route:

Lemma 1 (page 242 ,  11.20 Theorem):

If $\mu$ is a positive finite Borel measure on $R^1$ and $u=P[d\mu]$,then:

$$(M_{rad}u)(x)\leq(M\mu)(x)$$

Lemma 2 (page 243,  11.22 Theorem):

If $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on $R^1$ and $D\mu(x)=0$ for some $x$,then

$$ 
    \lim_{\lambda\to 0}u(x,\lambda)=0
    $$
PROOF By definition,the assumption $D\mu(x)=0$ means that
$$ \lim \mu(I)/m(I) =0$$
as the segments $I\subset R^1$ shrink to their center $x$.Pick $\epsilon>0$.One of these segments,say $I_0$,is then small enough to ensure that
$$ \mu(I)<\epsilon m(I)$$
for every $I\subset I_0$ that has $x$ as center,explicitly we assume $I_0=B(x,\delta),0 <\delta$.

Let $\mu_0$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $I_0$,put $\mu_1=\mu-\mu_0$,and let $u_i=P[d\mu_i](i=0,1)$.The integrands in 
$$u_1(x,\lambda)=\int_{R^1-I_0}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^{2}+(x-t)^{2}}d\mu(t)$$
$<(x-t)^{(-2)} \in L^1(R^1-I_0)$.Hence
$$\lim_{\lambda\to 0}u_1(x,\lambda)=0$$

Next,use Lemma 1 to see that
$$(M_{rad} u_0)(x)\leq (M\mu_0)(x)\leq  \epsilon $$

Hence
$$\limsup_{\lambda\to 0}u_0(x,\lambda)\leq \epsilon $$

Since $u=u_0 +u_1 $and $\epsilon$ was arbitrary,

$$\lim_{\lambda\to 0}u(x,\lambda)=0$$

Actually,this proof explains why  just using the definition of Lebesgue point can't approach the result.

Lemma 3 (page 244 , 11.23 Theorem)

If $f\in L^1(R^1)$,then

$$
\lim_{λ\to 0}f\ast h_{\lambda}(x)=f(x)
    $$
at every Lebesgue point $x$ of $f$.

PROOF let $k(t)=\chi_{ [-1,1] }(t)f(x) ,g(t)=f(t)-k(t)$
,a little computation shows
$$\lim_{λ\to 0}k\ast h_{\lambda}(x)=f(x)$$
So by subtracting $k(t)$ from $f$ we may assume,without loos of generality,that $f(x)=0$.Define a Borel measure $\mu$ on $R^1$ by
$$\mu(E)=\int_{E} |f| dm$$
Then the assumption $(D\mu)(x)=0$;hence $u=P[d\mu]$
$$\lim_{\lambda\to 0}u(x,\lambda)=0$$

The same is true of $f\ast h_{\lambda}$,because
$$|f\ast h_{\lambda}|\leq |f|\ast h_{\lambda} = P[d\mu]$$

More details refer to Big rudin chapter 11,follow this route you can also prove the resluts of Fej$\'{e}$r Theorem on $L^1(T)$ (page 252 ,Exer 24).